# Why is every prime except 2 and 5 a divisor of some 99...99?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I already know one answer to the question (which is why the question occurred to me).  Here it is:

If $p$ is a prime not equal to $2$ or $5$, then $\frac1p$ has a repeating decimal expression:
$$0.d_1d_2\cdots d_k\overline{e_1e_2\cdots e_\ell}$$
where the $d$'s and the $e$'s are digits.  Standard techniques (e.g. geometric series) show that 
$$\frac1p=\frac{d_1d_2\cdots d_k}{10^k}+\frac{e_1e_2\cdots e_\ell}{10^k(10^\ell-1)}=\frac{d_1d_2\cdots d_k\cdot(10^\ell-1)+e_1e_2\cdots e_\ell}{10^k(10^\ell-1)}$$
(Here $d_1d_2\cdots d_k$ and $e_1e_2\cdots e_\ell$ are not products but decimal expansions of integers.)

We can reduce this complicated fraction to $\frac1p$, so the denominator is a multiple of $p$.  But $p$ isn't $2$ or $5$, so $10^\ell-1$ is a multiple of $p$.

I have not thought about number theory much, but I imagine this follows from some standard undergraduate number-theorem.  Does anyone know one?  And does anyone know the history of the proof above?  Surely, lots of people teaching Calculus (like me, right now) have noticed this in the course of making tests.  Or have I made some mistake?

Comment: [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem)

Comment: @achillehui:  Thanks for satisfying my curiosity!  (And now, some undergrad number theory is coming back to me, after many years.)

Comment: It was a well known method of grade school that to as method to covert repeating decimals to fractions we let $N= a.bcd..f\overline{jklm...}$.  $10^l N =abcdf..... jklm...\overline{jklm...}$ so $10^lN - N = integer$ so $N = \frac {integer}{99999...}$ which meant that all fractions $\frac ab$ can be converted to $\frac {m}{99999....90000...}$ which struck me as an *amazing* coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is actually backwards, what you showed is that there exists $\ell$ such that $p\mid 10^\ell -1$ when $p\ne 2,5$. This is $10^\ell-1$ being divisible by the prime not the prime being divisible by $10^\ell-1$.

Nonetheless, this is true, and you gave an interesting argument for it. In general, this follows from a result known as Fermat's little theorem, which says that if $p\nmid a$,
then $p\mid a^{p-1}-1$.

**Note on notation:** $a\mid b$ is read as $a$ divides $b$ and means that $\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer.

I can't say I'm familiar with the proof you gave or its history though.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can go a little further.

Theorem 1:  For any  number, prime or not, $k$ then if $m=\gcd(k,10)$ then there is $99999....9999= 10^l$ so that $m$ divides into $10^l -1$

Pf:  You gave it.  Well, for a full proof we have to prove all decimals of rational numbers  repeat infinitely.  That's easy to show as there are only $m$ possible remainders and once a remainder comes up the second time you are in an infinite loop to repeat yourself.

Corrolaries:  If $\gcd(k, 3) = 1$ then there is a $111111.....l$ that $m$ divides into.  If $\gcd(k,9) = 3$ then there is a $333333.....3$ that $m$ divides into.

But here's a powerful *second* theorem.

Th 2:  If $p$ is a prime, then $p$ divides into $\frac {10^{p-1}-1}9= \underbrace{1111....111}_{p-1\text{ times}}$.

This is a direct result of Fermat's Little theorem that for any prime $p$ and and any $a;\gcd(a,p)=1$ that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ or in other words that $p$ divides into $a^{p-1}$.

I'm not going to prove FLT but, now that I think of it, it's a rather sophisticated variation of your argument.

Comment: Yes, your Theorem 2 is even cooler, in that it captures the full statement of Fermat's Little Theorem in a "high school arithmetic" context (as in my question).

Comment: By the way, FLT is almost universally "Fermat's *Last* Theorem".  Maybe the little one should be FLiT?  :)

Comment: No.  FLT is almost universally Faster Than Light.

Comment: Ancd CRT universally means Cathode Ray Tube.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem may be better known to the world in general but on these boards Fermat's Little Theorem is a *lot* more used and applicable.  I've *never* seen Fermat's Last Theorem referred to as FLT.  On these boards I've found FLT almost *always* means Fermat's Little Theorem (I can't think of an instance when it meant any thing else).  However I don't think we should use the abreviation without explanation first and on the whole must here don't.

Comment: Because Fermat's Little Theorem here is used more that Fermat's last and because FLT is nearly universally recognize as the Little Theorem, I'd suggest the last one be known as FLaT.

Comment: I have to admit I have no real basis for my "almost universally" assertion.  :)  I guess the best I can say is that, if I saw FLT in a number-theory context, I would think "Last".  (How much does that mean from the guy who admitted, earlier in the page, that he has forgotten most of his undergrad number theory?)